# Facebook access Token with longer expiration

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/#extend_token) on getting a token with longer expiration time  . The Facebook connect is done on the client side (Js sdk). The steps I take are:

- enabled 'deprecate offline_access' on my app settings page
- retreive the access_token as normal
- curl "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
      client_id=APP_ID&
      client_secret=APP_SECRET&
      grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
      fb_exchange_token=access_token"

This always returns the same exact same access token with expiration of 2 hours, shouldn't it return a token (same or not as access_token) that is valid 60 days ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of right now, in my experience, it seems that the 60 day tokens are returned for new users who add the app after the 'deprecate offline_access' setting is enabled.  Older users, from prior to setting the 'deprecate offline_access' setting seem to be stuck at 2 hour lifetime.

I also have some tests that seem to indicate that setting the 'Enhanced Auth Dialog' setting in addition to the 'deprecate offline_access' setting is required to get long lived tokens.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot @Greg_Whalin, the 'Enhanced Auth Dialog' was indeed necessary

Comment: Also using client side (desktop) auth, have both "deprecate offline_access" and "enhanced auth dialog" enabled. After whole authentication process, I get access token valid for 60 days. BUT I am not able to extend the validity by calling mentioned endpoint. It always returns the same token with same validity < 60 days. Any suggestions?

Comment: i have both of these set and i got a 60 day token. but after that i removed the app from my app settings, and now i only get 2 hour tokens :( any ideas?

Comment: Sweet. To me it seems that removing the app from the user and adding it again did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can programmatically set the 2hour token as expired using HTTP DELETE to `me/permissions`, this will force the user to re-auth your app.  Which should give you a 60 day token.